# How do I get the value of a global variable in a dll which is described by an ordinal not a name using ctypes in Python?

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I am accessing a dll from Python using the ctypes library. The functions in the dll are accessible by ordinal, rather than name. I can inspect the dll using Dependency Walker and relate the ordinals to function names. There is a global error number variable in the dll which I wish to access. Dependency Walker shows that it has an ordinal value of 13.

There seems to be no way of accessing a global variable by ordinal using ctypes.

If the global variable were named then it seems I would be able to do something like:

error_value = c_int.in_dll(my_dll_handle, "my_error_value")
(https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#accessing-values-exported-from-dlls)

Any ideas as to how I access the global variable given only an ordinal?

Comment: I've never used this but there is a section on the page you linked that appears to discuss this. I just searched for ordinal. See if that works.

Comment: The page linked shows how to use ordinals for functions, not variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see anything explicit in the documentation, other than the syntax for *functions* accessed by ordinal.  Through experimentation, the following worked:

Test code:

```
int x = 5;
int func(int a) { return a*2; }
```

.DEF file exporting by ordinal:

```
EXPORTS
  x @1 NONAME DATA
  func @2 NONAME
```

Python code:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> test = CDLL('test')
>>> test[2](5)           # Call ordinal 2 function.
10
>>> test[1]              # Ordinal 1 thinks it is a function pointer.
<_FuncPtr object at 0x0000000002FEA048>
>>> cast(test[1],POINTER(c_int)).contents        # cast?
c_long(5)                                        # Worked!
>>> cast(test[1],POINTER(c_int)).contents.value
5
```